# RawCap error:"Unable to enter promiscuous mode (RCVALL_ON), using RCVALL_SOCKETLEVELONLY."

Tags: localhost, windows-xp, packet-capture, loopback, raw-ethernet

I am attempting to capture localhost(loopback 127.0.0.1) TCP traffic between master-slave (server-client) programs on my PC. Wireshark cannot do this, but I understand that RawCap does.

When I try to run the program, RawCap says `"Unable to enter promiscuous mode (RCVALL_ON), using RCVALL_SOCKETLEVELONLY."`

Any idea what is causing this?

much thanks!

Comment: You should contact the developer...

Comment: same problem. cant find any solution. winxp

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run RawCap as an administrator to enter Promiscuous Mode.

Comment: I'm running rawcap under administrator right, but experiencing that error.

Answer (score -1):

See steps below to install loopback adapter. Note that the steps below may be slightly different for your specific Microsoft OS version may but the idea is same:

To install Microsoft Loopback Adapter:

1. In the host operating system, right-click My Computer, and then select Properties. Depending on the style of the start menu, My Computer may be located in the Start menu.
2. In the System Properties dialog box, on the Hardware tab, click Add Hardware Wizard.
3. In the Add Hardware dialog box, click Next.
4. When the Is the hardware connected? dialog box appears, click Yes, I have already connected the hardware, and then click Next.
5. In the Installed hardware list, click Add a new hardware device, and then click Next.
6. In the What do you want the wizard to do? list, click Install the hardware that I manually select from a list (Advanced), and then click Next.
7. In the Common hardware types list, click Network adapters, and then click Next.
8. In the Manufacturer list, click Microsoft.
9. In the Network Adapter list, click Microsoft Loopback Adapter, and then click Next twice.
10. If a message about driver signing appears, click Continue Anyway.
11. In the Completing the Add Hardware Wizard dialog box, click Finish, and then click OK.